# Subversion Moving File

Tags: eclipse, subclipse

I'm developing a project under Eclipse/Subclipse, and it looks like Subclipse is misbehaving.

For some reason, a file (let's call it `report.xml`) keeps getting renamed `report.xml.svntmp`.  (I'm assuming Subclipse is the culprit based on that extension; I don't know for certain that it really is.)  Obviously, this is causing problems for the code that would like to have a look at that file.  Anybody have any ideas on what's causing this and how to make it stop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, do not copy SVN-managed folders from one project to another.  You copy over some SVN information, which will cause Subclipse to get confused and a bit destructive.

Answer (score 1):

Does it go away if you refresh?  The only thing that uses that file extension is some code to fix drag and drop copy and paste operations in Eclipse. Eclipse sends these through as a File Delete which causes Subclipse to run svn delete.  There is some code in place to detect when the file is then immediately replaced with a new version.  To undo the delete, we have to run svn revert.  However, that would also replace the file contents. So the current file contents are put in the .svntmp file and then moved back in place after the revert runs.

See:
http://subclipse.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=772

http://subclipse.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=781

Comment: Looks like the problem was being caused by me copying over some bad SVN information; once I got rid of that, the problem went away.